# character before first child node and after last child node in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<line>
      <orig><gap quantity="4" unit="chars" reason="illegible"/> <gap quantity="4"
      unit="chars" reason="illegible"/> <gap quantity="3" unit="chars"
      reason="illegible"/> <gap quantity="5" unit="chars" reason="illegible"/>
      shal <gap quantity="2" unit="chars" reason="illegible"/> <gap
      quantity="12" unit="chars" reason="illegible"/> </orig>
 </line>
```

I'd like to apply some styling to it such that every time there is a sequence of  nodes in a row, the first gap node is prefaced with a left square bracket and the last  node is followed by a right square bracket.  A number of dots, taken from the @quantity element in , will be displayed for each gap node  So, for example, the xml above should look like this:

[.... .... ... .....] shal [.. ............]

I've written a template that adds the bracket before the first  node and after the last  node, so it looks like this:

[.... .... ... ..... shal .. ............]

My xslt code is here:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:orig/tei:gap">
    <xsl:variable name="max" select="@quantity"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::tei:gap)">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $max">
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::tei:gap)">
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>        
</xsl:template>
```

How would I handle the other brackets?  I thought I might be able to do it by writing a template that applies to the  node directly by stepping up a level and using position(), but that just wraps each set of dots in square brackets instead of only wrapping the beginning and ending of each sequence of  nodes.

**EDIT:**  My original sample XML was confusing and didn't accurately explain what I need to make happen, so hopefully this new piece will help out in that regard.

Comment: Do you have **adjacent** gaps that you wish to group? There are none in your example, but you are testing for preceding sibling gaps, apparently for no good reason.

Comment: Good point.  I grabbed a random example (sorry about that...I was asking from the airport) but it's possible for a line to have multiple adjacent gaps separated by a space.  My goal is checking for preceding a sibling and following a sibling was to get the first and last gaps, although I suppose what I really need is the first and last gap in any particular grouping of them within the <orig> node.

Comment: Ugh, sorry about the horrible comment...phone autocorrect is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If - as it seems - you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use the `<xsl:for-each-group>` instruction to group adjacent `gap` elements. For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="orig">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::gap)">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:for-each select="1 to @quantity">
                            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=""/>
            </xsl:otherwise>  
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your (new) example, will return:

```
[.... .... ... .....]
      shal [.. ............]
```

Comment: I am using 2.0.

I edited my original post to show something more akin to what I'm dealing with, and applied your suggested fix to it.  What I'm getting as a result is [....] [....] [...] [.....] shal [..] [............], and what I'd like to get as a result is [.... .... ... .....] shal [.. ............].

Comment: @medievalmatt I am unable to reproduce your result. I have edited my answer slightly to accommodate the requirement of having a space separating between groups of dots, but that's irrelevant to your comment. -- P.S. Note the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instruction in my stylesheet.

Comment: Adding "tei:orig" to my list of items in strip-space fixed the issue I was running into when I run it against just the line I provided, but in my actual implementation I'm now getting a weird thing where my text repeats.  However, your fix works for what I provided and I can try to suss that out on my own.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information about where you locate the problem? I've just wrote as example following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="hi">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="orig | line">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="gap">
<xsl:variable name="max" select="@quantity"/>
<xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $max">
   <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>]</xsl:text>  
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input XML

```
<line>
  <orig><hi>W</hi>e be <gap quantity="4" unit="chars" reason="illegible"/>
        ed and moeued of <gap quantity="6" unit="chars" reason="illegible"/>
  </orig>
</line>
```

the following output is produced

```
We be [....]ed and moeued of [......]
```

I'm just not sure why it's necessary to check the preceding and following nodes when applying templates to the `gap` element, maybe it's just a misunderstanding.

Comment: As I mentioned above I picked a bad bit of example code.  It's possible for there to be two adjacent gap nodes.  When that happens, I need the brackets to surround the grouping, not the individual items.  That's why I was using preceding-sibling.  When I am back home and not answering on my phone I'll provide another example that might better illustrate the issue.